# How can I check if a website displays true or false?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roblox

Is it possible for javascript to check if the website says true or false? It's literally a blank page and depending on the url (the code changes it depending on some stuff) it just says "true" or false. It also says that in the source bit in inspect element.

Here is the website: https://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?userId=130948426&assetId=4672521661

```
        if (username){
    roblox.getIdFromUsername(username).then(id => {
      var tokenID = `https://api.roblox.com/ownership/hasasset?userId=${id}&assetId=4672521661`

      message.channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle("Checking Purchases..").setDescription(`${tokenID} Hold Tight! We are just checking if you purchased a class!`).setFooter("Getroles").setColor("#ff4757")).then(() => {
        if(!(tokenID() === true)){
message.channel.send('You have bought it!');
}
```

Username is defied. So when I do the command, it just sends the embed and nothing else. I'm quite stuck on this bit

Answer (score 0):

Use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fetch the webpage.

```
axios.get(tokenID).then(({data}) => {
   console.log(data) // debug
   const bought = data === 'true'
   // ...send message to user
})
```

Comment: I've did this:

http://prntscr.com/r63aa1 
But it does not work and it gets an error

Comment: Take at look at where it says the error is. It's in a different file. app/handlers/command.js on line 21.

Comment: Oh, its coming from here:

http://prntscr.com/r63hlc

But when I remove the getroles.js file (the one with the tokenID etc) the error goes. Should I open another question?

Comment: Reformat your code using the IDE formatter. That really long line there? Break it on the dots. You need to test if `bought` is true also, because it will be false if the website said false.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite new to scripting at the moment.
How can I format it?
And what break?

Comment: Type the name of your IDE (is it WebStorm?) into Google along with "Format Code".